# ASP.NET: Assign a variable before rendering user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

(New to ASP.NET here.)

I have a user control which should check for a value in the request query string before deciding what to render:

```
<%# softLoaded ? "HELLO" : "GOOD BYE" %>
```

This is the code-behind for the user control:

```
public bool softLoaded { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    softLoaded = "apply".Equals(Request.QueryString["apply"]);
}
```

I've debugged the application and found that `softLoaded` is `true` when it should be and `false` when it should be, but no matter what the value is, the generated HTML says "GOOD BYE" (as if the value was `false`). This makes me believe that `Page_Load` is called "too late", causing the `.ascx` file to use the default value of the bool, which is `false`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I need to call `DataBind()` in the `Page_Load` method of my control to actually make stuff happen. I don't fully grasp how it works, but it sure does!

Comment: # is tells ASP.NET to evaluate the expression OnDataBind and you were not DataBinding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a databinding expression. You need to set the variable value any time before the databinding occurs. Page_Load, OnInit or OnPreInit for example.